# how to make tablayout transperent in android

Tags: android

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:tabBackground="@android:color/transparent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!--<include layout="@layout/toolbar" android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"/>-->
    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#90a0c020" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

above is my xml code i am trying to make bottom tab-layout with transparent background but i am unable to  make it i have applied transparent background color in tab layout but its not working.

current screen :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gStei.png)

expected screen :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQFW3.png)

Please help me with this .
Thanks

Comment: what is your exact problem? your `TabLayout` is half transparent on the screenshot, just like you set with `android:background="#90000000"`...

Comment: Thanks for helping , actually i want  transparent of bottom tab background only text should visible with  transparent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have set `android:background="#90000000"` as background, which means

1. use `#000000` color (black), last 6 chars, just like in HTML
2. apply transparency with `#90`, first 2 chars (about half, range is from `00` to `ff`, hex)

and you are getting dark-gray-half-transparent color, which mixed with underlying black color (background of fragments in `ViewPager`) gives you just very-dark-gray. just for testing try to replace two random character, e.g. try with `"#90a0c020"`

if you want full transparency just se first param to `00`, so `android:background="#00000000"`. or you may use built-in definition `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

[HERE](https://gist.github.com/lopspower/03fb1cc0ac9f32ef38f4) you can find a nice tools and some useful comments

edit - sample:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#9078fa"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!--<include layout="@layout/toolbar" android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"/>-->
    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks i have already tried with this solution but still its  not showing transparent.

Comment: post in your question screenshot with `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` set for `TabLayout`. currently you have posted code with `"#90000000"`, which is obvious mistake and not-fully-transparent color

Comment: paste.ofcode.org/bagAeqdyHPLhMY4nm8xXk5  this code and pasteboard.co/xMVxyFOW0o3t.png this screen  i don't know where i am doing mistake put https starting link

Comment: what color are you expecting under `TabLayout` when you apply full transparency? parent of `TabLayout` - `LinearLayout` - doesn't have any color set for background, so its also transparent... so you will se default background of `Window`, which is set by styling and depends on light/dark mode, white or black. try to set some color for `LinearLayout` and keep `"@android:color/transparent"` set for `TabLayout`

Comment: can you check my UI i have update my ui code what i am doing wrong please help

Comment: I've posted a sample with `RelativeLayout` as you modified your code in the meantime

Comment: This is fine but i want keep 70% transparent can we apply this ?

Comment: yep, just use this 70% transparent color for `TabLayout`, but still keep a "main background" color (not transparent at all) set for root layout in XML (in current code its `RelativeLayout`, previously you had `LinearLayout`, generaly first item in XML)